PVC in wrong location need to transition from there to around the corner to subpanel
There was a 1" and 2 3/4 PVC ran to the wrong location they brought them up on the front corner of the house about a foot away from the edge .
The subpanel is located a foot and a half from the corner on the side of the house
It is too close of a run to try to use PVC  I am going to be using the liquid tight to turn the 1" and the 2- 3/4 by using LL's to bring them towards the corner use LB's at the corner and up to the subpanel.
In between the condolets will only be a foot.
There are only 2 90's in the runs currently

A picture would be really helpful with this question.

This is indecipherable without pictures. It's also multiple questions that should not all be in one question. One question per question works much better here. Take the [tour]

You've gone from multiple questions to no questions.

It very much depends on how many bends are already in the conduit. Odds are that you will need an accessible pulling point (junction box or LB/LL/LR) if you're going to add a bunch more bends to get where it goes, in order to remain at or below 360 degrees of bending between pulling points.
Liquid-tight is the nastiest stuff for pulling in. PVC is much easier, so sticking with PVC is probably a better idea.
Will update if you post pictures illustrating the problem. But those points apply regardless.
